# How to convert grpc.ServerInterceptor to grcp.aio.ServerInterceptor

Tags: python-asyncio, grpc, prometheus, grpc-python

I am trying to implement async ServerInterceptor [grcp.aio.ServerInterceptor]. My current synchronous ServerInterceptor looks like this https://github.com/zhyon404/python-grpc-prometheus/blob/master/python_grpc_prometheus/prometheus_server_interceptor.py#L48. When i try to use grpc.aio.ServerInterceptor and start the server,
My Server code

```
from grpc_opentracing import open_tracing_server_interceptor
from grpc_opentracing.grpcext import intercept_server


import PromServerInterceptor

class MyServicer():
    async def _start_async_server(self, tracer=None,service, grpc_port=8083, http_port=8080):
        tracing_interceptor = open_tracing_server_interceptor(tracer)

       
        server = aio.server(nterceptors=(PromServerInterceptor(),))
        server = intercept_server(server, tracing_interceptor)
        my_service_pb2_grpc.add_MyServicer_to_server(service, server)
        server.add_insecure_port("[::]:" + str(grpc_port))
        await server.start()
        logger.info("Started prometheus server at port %s", http_port)
        prometheus_client.start_http_server(http_port)
        await server.wait_for_termination()

 def async_serve(self, tracer=None, service, grpc_port=8083, http_port=8080):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(self._start_async_server(service, tracer, grpc_port, http_port))
    loop.run_forever()

Following are the lib versions i am using:

    grpcio=1.32.0
    grpcio-opentracing==1.1.4


I see the following error:
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/aio/server.pyx.pxi", line 646, in grpc._cython.cygrpc._handle_exceptions
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/aio/server.pyx.pxi", line 745, in _handle_rpc
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/aio/server.pyx.pxi", line 511, in _handle_unary_unary_rpc
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/aio/server.pyx.pxi", line 368, in _finish_handler_with_unary_response
  File "prometheus_server_interceptor.py", line 93, in new_behavior
    rsp = await behavior(request_or_iterator, service_context)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc_opentracing/grpcext/_interceptor.py", line 272, in adaptation
    _UnaryServerInfo(self._method), handler)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc_opentracing/_server.py", line 145, in intercept_unary
    timeout=servicer_context.time_remaining(),
AttributeError: 'grpc._cython.cygrpc._ServicerContext' object has no attribute 'time_remaining
```

Following is my PromServerInterceptor implemenation:

```
from grpc import aio
import grpc

from timeit import default_timer

from python_grpc_prometheus.server_metrics import (SERVER_HANDLED_LATENCY_SECONDS,
                                                   SERVER_HANDLED_COUNTER,
                                                   SERVER_STARTED_COUNTER,
                                                   SERVER_MSG_RECEIVED_TOTAL,
                                                   SERVER_MSG_SENT_TOTAL)
from python_grpc_prometheus.util import type_from_method
from python_grpc_prometheus.util import code_to_string


def _wrap_rpc_behavior(handler, fn):
    if handler is None:
        return None

    if handler.request_streaming and handler.response_streaming:
        behavior_fn = handler.stream_stream
        handler_factory = grpc.stream_stream_rpc_method_handler
    elif handler.request_streaming and not handler.response_streaming:
        behavior_fn = handler.stream_unary
        handler_factory = grpc.stream_unary_rpc_method_handler
    elif not handler.request_streaming and handler.response_streaming:
        behavior_fn = handler.unary_stream
        handler_factory = grpc.unary_stream_rpc_method_handler
    else:
        behavior_fn = handler.unary_unary
        handler_factory = grpc.unary_unary_rpc_method_handler

    return handler_factory(fn(behavior_fn,
                              handler.request_streaming,
                              handler.response_streaming),
                           request_deserializer=handler.request_deserializer,
                           response_serializer=handler.response_serializer)


def split_call_details(handler_call_details, minimum_grpc_method_path_items=3):
    parts = handler_call_details.method.split("/")
    if len(parts) < minimum_grpc_method_path_items:
        return '', '', False

    grpc_service, grpc_method = parts[1:minimum_grpc_method_path_items]
    return grpc_service, grpc_method, True


class PromServerInterceptor(aio.ServerInterceptor):
    async def intercept_service(self, continuation, handler_call_details):

        handler = await continuation(handler_call_details)
        if handler is None:
            return handler

        # only support unary
        if handler.request_streaming or handler.response_streaming:
            return handler

        grpc_service, grpc_method, ok = split_call_details(handler_call_details)
        if not ok:
            return continuation(handler_call_details)

        grpc_type = type_from_method(handler.request_streaming, handler.response_streaming)

        SERVER_STARTED_COUNTER.labels(
            grpc_type=grpc_type,
            grpc_service=grpc_service,
            grpc_method=grpc_method).inc()

        def latency_wrapper(behavior, request_streaming, response_streaming):
            async def new_behavior(request_or_iterator, service_context):
                start = default_timer()

                SERVER_MSG_RECEIVED_TOTAL.labels(
                    grpc_type=grpc_type,
                    grpc_service=grpc_service,
                    grpc_method=grpc_method
                ).inc()

                # default
                code = code_to_string(grpc.StatusCode.UNKNOWN)

                try:
                    rsp = await behavior(request_or_iterator, service_context)
                    if service_context._state.code is None:
                        code = code_to_string(grpc.StatusCode.OK)
                    else:
                        code = code_to_string(service_context._state.code)

                    SERVER_MSG_SENT_TOTAL.labels(
                        grpc_type=grpc_type,
                        grpc_service=grpc_service,
                        grpc_method=grpc_method
                    ).inc()

                    return rsp
                except grpc.RpcError as e:
                    if isinstance(e, grpc.Call):
                        code = code_to_string(e.code())

                    raise e
                finally:
                    SERVER_HANDLED_COUNTER.labels(
                        grpc_type=grpc_type,
                        grpc_service=grpc_service,
                        grpc_method=grpc_method,
                        grpc_code=code
                    ).inc()

                    SERVER_HANDLED_LATENCY_SECONDS.labels(
                        grpc_type=grpc_type,
                        grpc_service=grpc_service,
                        grpc_method=grpc_method).observe(max(default_timer() - start, 0))

            return new_behavior

        return _wrap_rpc_behavior(handler, latency_wrapper)
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to await something, but without seeing your code, especially the line raising the exception, it's hard to say more. Please edit your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: @dirn I have added the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

The interceptor from grpc.aio can look like:

```py
    class RequestIdInterceptor(grpc.aio.ServerInterceptor):
        async def intercept_service(self, continuation, handler_call_details):
            for (header, value) in handler_call_details.invocation_metadata:
                if header == "request_id":
                    ...
                    break
            return await continuation(handler_call_details)
```

To convert it you need to add `async` for `intercept_service` and `await` for `continuation`.